# Grep and remove lines with a blank field value

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, cut

I was wondering if there's any command to look for blank field values of a text file and remove the entire line.

Example

```
 Hello:Its Me
 Hello:How are you
 Hello:
 Hello:Bye
```

And expected output

```
 Hello:Its Me
 Hello:How are you
 Hello:Bye
```

Comment: do add your own efforts to solve to question when asking... your previous question didn't get an answer, but somehow you've got it for this one.. :)

Answer (score 5):

Very standard case, the simplest solution with `awk` would be

```
awk -F: '$2 != ""' file
```

and with `grep`:

```
grep :. file
```

Answer (score 3):

If you mean to skip `Hello:` lines you can use something like:

```
awk -F: '{if($2 != "") print }' input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

At least with GNU awk, and I think with any version of awk, the default action when something evaluates to `true` is to print. So, if you set the field delimiter to `:`, to print lines that have a second field, all you need is:

```
$ awk -F: '$2' file
Hello:Its Me
Hello:How are you
Hello:Bye
```

However, this will also print cases where the second field is whitespace (a space, or a tab etc), but will *not* print the line if second field is one or multiple `0`s, because `awk` evaluates this as false.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is easier to define the remove conditions (`grep -v`). Example remove when last field is empty:

```
grep -v ':$' file
```